# What different between md5() .vs. hash when saving password?

Tags: php, encryption, hash

Today, I have a discussed with my friend about security with a website.

I am usually using a hash with random salts when saving a password of the user.

Because hash can't decompile, my friend often using `md5()` to encrypt password of the user.

Problem is:

I tried to explain to him, md5() can decryption, but he took:

> " I can using `md5(md5(md5('password')))` or `md5() + random string` ".

So, I also mention about this will have much time to save into database, when the user login, again to decryption.

But it also not enough to convince. Have anyone can suggest me how to explain easily to understand?

Thanks.

Comment: look at here http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/what-are-the-differences-between-md5-sha-and-rsa

Comment: Look great. I did not find it before creating this question. Thank you very much @DCoder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MD5 is a hash function (one way) and cannot be decrypted, the problems with MD5 for password storing are different.

- MD5 is ways too fast for hashing passwords, one can calculate about 100 Giga MD5 per second with a good GPU. That makes brute-forcing too easy, testing a whole english dictionary is a matter of micro seconds.
- Combining MD5 like md5(md5(md5('password'))) does not add much of security, password cracker tools often offer this out of the box.

That is why we should use a hash function with a cost factor like BCrypt. The cost factor determines how much time is used to calculate a single hash, it should be as much as your server can bear. PHP offers the function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to generate safe password hashes.

Comment: You said `md5()` too fast. Are you think using it to save password? And function `password_hash()` is best solution with `md5()`?

Comment: `md5` cannot be decrypted? But I don't know this line: `That makes brute-forcing too easy, testing a whole english dictionary is a matter of micro seconds.`. It means? `md5` can decrypt?

Comment: Yes the worst problem with MD5 is its fastness. The function password_hash() is the best option, it is future proof (the used algorithm can be exchanged) and it is implemented in native code. Brute-forcing is not decryption, you can find textes that result in the same hash, but you can never be sure if it is the original password, there is an infinite number of matching textes.

Comment: I understand. But you said: `MD5 is a hash function (one way) and cannot be decrypted`. After, you said it can be descrypt with brute-forcing base on dictionary.

Comment: @VănLộc - An encryption algorithmus like AES offers decryption, that means there exists an algorithmus to get from the cyphertext back to the plaintext. A hash algorithmus like SHA does not offer such a way back. The only option you have instead, is to guess the password and check whether it results in the same hash, then you can assume it was the original password (cracking). For a strong password it is impossible to make enough guesses to find the password (even with MD5), for short passwords from users, 100Giga guesses per second is enough to often find a match.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, your answer more useful to me, I will check accept to another user can see. Good look.

Comment: @VănLộc - Just an example, take the cross sum from 45, it is 9. This is our hash function. Now you can try all possible values, 1, 2, ..., 45 then you find a match, so we cracked the hash! But we cannot be sure that 45 was the original password, the number 63 would also give a match, a cross sum cannot be decrypted back.

Comment: Excellent example. Thanks your example helpful

Answer (score 0):

- MD5 and SHA are hash functions (SHA is actually a family of hash functions) - they take a piece of data, compact it and create a suitably unique output that is very hard to emulate with a different piece of data. They don't encrypt anything - you can't take MD5 or SHA output and "unhash" it to get back to your starting point. The difference between the two lies in what algorithm they use to create the hash. Also note that MD5 is now broken as a way was discovered to easily generate collisions and should not be used nor trusted anymore.
- RSA is an assymetric encryption algorithm. You have two keys (private and public) and you can perform a function with one key (encrypt or decrypt) and reverse with the other key. Which key you use depends on whether you are trying to do a digital signature or an encryption.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. RSA can use decryption, but it has a time depending on a category like 64bit - 128bit - 256bit.